# How to drop/create schema with peewee mysql

Tags: peewee

I know I can use the fallowing to drop all tables in schema.

```
database.drop_tables(database.get_tables())
```

But is there a way to actually delete the entire schema all together?

Answer (score 4):

> But is there a way to actually delete the entire schema all together?

I'm not sure what you mean "the entire schema"?

Peewee models are just python classes. You can gather up all your model classes into a list or whatever. What I typically do in my projects is, in the entrypoint, have a list of all models:

```
from some_app.models import Foo, Bar, Baz
from other_app.models import Nug

MODELS = (Bar, Baz, Foo, Nug)

def recreate_tables():
    db.drop_tables(MODELS)
    db.create_tables(MODELS)
```

Aside from that, it depends on your db engine. For sqlite you can just delete the file. For MySQL or Postgres you can use the sql shell or various sql commands.